# Installing 32bit-python-3.4 in wine in 64bit Linux

Tags: python, linux, wine

I have installed 64bit Debian Stable Linux which is running very well:

```
Linux debian 4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to install 32bit python-3.4 in it (for XP Windows support also). I tried:

```
$ wine msiexec /i python-3.4.0.msi
```

but got following error:

```
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:module:import_dll Loading library python34.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\python34\\python.exe") failed (error c000007b).
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\python34\\python.exe" failed, status c0000135
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"UpdatePip" returned 1627
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"ExecuteAction" returned 1627
```

On trying to run it:

```
$ wine python
```

The error is:

```
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python.exe"
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks for your help.

---

Edit: This is obviously not ideal method to install Python for Windows, but it is very convenient since one can work in Linux to develop and test applications and then create executable files for Windows using pyinstaller in wine. This works very well in Debian Stable 32bit Linux.

Python is installed in `~/.wine/drive_c/python34` as follows:

```
$ ls -l
total 4168
drwxr-xr-x 34 cardio cardio    4096 Feb 13 15:10 Lib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 cardio cardio  102400 Mar 16  2014 py.exe
-rw-r--r--  1 cardio cardio 4044800 Mar 16  2014 python34.dll
-rwxr-xr-x  1 cardio cardio  102912 Mar 16  2014 pyw.exe
drwxr-xr-x  2 cardio cardio    4096 Feb 12 08:23 Scripts
drwxr-xr-x  5 cardio cardio    4096 Feb 11 23:10 Tools
```

But on running py.exe:

```
$ wine ./py.exe 
Can't find a default Python.
```

Following also does not work:

```
$ wine python34.exe
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python34.exe"
```

---

Edit: As suggested by @laszlowaty in comments, I installed python34 (64bit) in Windows and copied the python34 folder to wine c_disk, but it does not work:

```
$ wine ./python.exe
err:module:import_dll Library python34.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Python34\\python.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\Python34\\python.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

I could not find python34.dll in Windows.

---

Edit: I had to do a reinstall of my Debian Stable 64bit Linux distribution. After this I again tried and python-3.4.0.msi installed perfectly well this time. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: I cannot understand why you need to install python for windows on linux...

Comment: This not proper way to use python inside wine. if you have still doubt on it this ref https://github.com/ossbuild/ossbuild-main/issues/7

Comment: I have added in my question why I am using this approach.

Comment: Have you tried `wine 'C:\python34\python.exe'`?

Comment: There is no such file so it is not surprising that it does not work.

Comment: error c000007b is invalid image format, often resulting from trying to load a 64 bit object on a 32 bit system. I can only suggest to ditch 32 bit anything ASAP.

Answer (score 2):

it makes perfect sense to install python on wine.
- cross platform development
- development for scripts used under wine (there are differences between windows and wine that needs to be adressed, for instance in the registry)
- we use wine to replace some windows boxes, because it is faster in many cases

And if You create multiprocessing multi-platform code that should run álso on Windows, I stongly recommend to test on windows/wine, because windows is the most limited os (I am talking about : no forking on Windows, no Signals on Windows, Functions and Classes must be pickable to spawn a new process, etc... )

Nowadays most Programs I develop on Windows, and test them parallel on Linux / Osx (because usually there they will most likely run anyway)

I made a build example here, it contains bash scripts to automatically install Wine and Python on Your Ubuntu machine :

https://github.com/bitranox/install_python_on_wine_and_travis

Answer (score -1):

I have used this guide for 3.4 and 3.5.  Here is what you need to do:

```
#1 Use Wine 2.4
apt install add-apt-repository
add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel


#2 Use winetricks (a newer one that what is available in the repo)
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
./winetricks -q win10
./winetricks vcrun2015

#3 run the installer
wine python-3.4.4.exe
```

Source: http://realtechtalk.com/How_To_Install_python_34_35_and_up_on_Linux_with_wine_Working_Solution-2288-articles

Comment: ./winetricks -q win10 gives "bash ./winetricks: Premission denied". What does the #1 part actually do?

Answer (score -3):

This is terrible way to do it. Python is build as `portable`, this means you can just install python for your debian (in fact there is python shipped with debian, but you can install more versions of python).

If you have some specific reason to use windows version, `wine` is not a way to go. Much better (and easier) way is to use `VirtualBox` and emulate whole windows. I am not even sure if it's possible to fully run python using wine.

edit: Can you go to your `C` drive in wine and find where is your python.exe file?

Comment: I have added in my question why I am using this approach.

Comment: I made edit to my answer. Can you check where is your `python.exe` file in wine `c` drive?

Comment: Did you try `wine ~/.wine/drive_c/python34/python.exe`?

Comment: VirtualBox doesn't include Windows, so it isn't a solution unless you happen to have a spare Windows license hanging around.

Comment: @rnso Do you have anywhere in your `c` drive `python.exe` file?

Comment: Yes, there is ~/.wine/drive_c/Python27/python.exe . I had installed python2.7 earlier.

Comment: There is one more way to try it. Download and install python3 on windows machine and copy whole folder to your drive_c in linux. Try running it then.

Comment: Good idea. I will try and post the feedback here.

Comment: No, it did not work. Pl see edit in my question above.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is missing `python34.dll`. Can you copy this file from windows and place it in the wine? In the same folder as `python.exe` or in system32/64. It should get us moving further.

Comment: Pl see the latest edit in my answer and thanks for your help.